# Global mappers for keycloak client

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

For my use case, I would like to add certain attributes(derived from roles) to all the JWTs. And this would be needed for multiple clients. Is there a way to define mappers for all the clients under a realm in a given Keycloak instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't define "global mappers".
Scope can be used for this "global" approach. Use some your default scope (scope which is executed implicitly), which is default for all your clients, (for example `profile` scope usually) and define your "global" mapper(s) there.